# Rendering and Designing Clickable Landscapes for a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

I am trying to implement a clickable landscape for my React app. Similar to the image attached. I'm having difficulty describing my question and picking what type of framework to implement this with. I do know that this isn't possible with a simple material UI styling.

[Here is what I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JvFi.jpg)

Some more details:

1. Id like to be able to design a dock structure on the fly (or at least quickly) for a client.
2. Id like for the image to have clickable cells. For example: Click a boat slip to see the associated info

Any help for what type of framework I'm describing here would be appreciated. I'm not asking HOW to do this. I am just asking for a direction to take my research. Thank you

I've tried looking at how this is implemented with JavaScript games but not much luck.

Comment: This is known as an [image map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map), search for that term instead of "clickable landscape".

Comment: The choice of frontend framework is mostly irrelevant. You'll surely find a number of image map libraries for any framework. As for "quickly designing/editing", that depends on the data structure that the chosen library uses, and whether there's an editor for it.